# How To Run Selenium With Chrome In Docker

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, docker, google-chrome

I installed google-chrome in a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), but when I run my [Python 2](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-272/) script of [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), it failed like this:

```
automation@1c17781fef0c:/topology-editor/test$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 185, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 249, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.4.0-83-generic x86_64)
```

And if I run google-chrome directly in docker, it shows below:

```
automation@1c17781fef0c:/topology-editor/test$ google-chrome
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
automation@1c17781fef0c:/topology-editor/test$
```

System:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 1c17781fef0c 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 60.0.3112.78
$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8)
```

Comment: did you manage to do this?

Comment: @lub0v there are 2 choci to run chrome in docker:1. use `selenium/standalone-chrome` from selenium. 2. Build Dockerfile and install chrome, use headless way to run browser

Comment: https://github.com/joyzoursky/docker-python-chromedriver

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You need to launch a standalone chrome browser

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

and then in your python script launch browser using Remote webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

If you want you can also launch a Selenium Grid hub.

To do this as a django test do the following:

```
# docker-compose.yml

selenium:
  image: selenium/standalone-firefox
  ports:
  - 4444:4444

# project/app/test.py

from django.test import TestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


class SiteTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = [
        'app/fixtures/app.json',
        ...
    ]

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Remote("http://selenium:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_visit_site(self):
        self.browser.get('http://app:8000/')
        self.assertIn(self.browser.title, 'Home')
```

**Note:**

If you use `webdriver.ChromeOptions|FirefoxOptions|etc` then `DesiredCapabalities` import is not necessary:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # example
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", options=options)
```

Comment: I've tried and run successfully with selenium/standalone-chrome. I failed this because I want to integrate chrome/selenium with another docker images we used before. I'll try the Remote way to run, thanks.

Comment: After a lot of searching in different places I found this to be the answer that worked best for me

Comment: I someone help me to understand why remote link is "http://127.0.0.1" ?

Comment: @MertTheGreat, that was updated by someone else but the `127.0.0.1` was just an example. In docker it would be `selenium`

Comment: It worked for me as I saw that the container that has my app had connected to the selenium container, but the chrome UI did not show up, I did not put it in the headless mode and there was no error, did I miss anything?

Comment: Hi, Do you have a Java example? Thanks

Comment: How do you run the standalone when you want to run this through AWS ECR? e.g i am confused where to put the following docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome

Comment: @mgd6 you'll add to the `docker-compose.yml`, as shown in the answer

Answer (score 64):

You need to add the next lines to your Dockerfile:

```
# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# install selenium
RUN pip install selenium==3.8.0
```

Then your code should be like this. Especially you need to declare your `driver` like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('www.google.com')
screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('test.png')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Nice work for your configuration with `chrome_options` to start chrome in *headless* mode

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'd also mention that the Dockerfile could be improved to follow https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/ and produce less layers/less size. For example, all RUN instructions could be combined into one. Also, we don't need to have /tmp/chromedriver.zip file as part of the image and we can remove it after unpacking. Two apt-get install commands can be combined into one.

Comment: I like how you downloaded a screenshot, so one can see it's actually working

Comment: It solves quite a few problems but it still doesn't work for me. My  script does more than just taking a screenshot and I guess this introduces various new problems. First, there is the tab crash issue, and if you solve that then you have a timeout issue.

Comment: Worth making more explicit as I had issues with this but then resolved...
First line of dockerfile should be FROM python:latest

Comment: If you are getting the error:
`InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: headless chrome=***.*.****.**)`
When executing `driver.get('www.google.com')`
Try `driver.get('https://www.google.com/')` that worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

For people coming through google search, here is the easiest workaround:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils

#download and install chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

#install python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt 
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt 

#some envs
ENV APP_HOME /app 
ENV PORT 5000

#set workspace
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

#copy local files
COPY . . 

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :${PORT} --workers 1 --threads 8 main:app
```

You will need to install chromedriver_binary pip package which I have added in `requirements.txt` as:

```
Flask==1.1.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
selenium==3.141.0
chromedriver-binary==79.0.3945.36
```

Then your `main.py` should be like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary


chrome_options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1400,2100") 
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Now, build your `Dockerfile` using `docker build -t <imagename> .` and `docker run --rm -p <yourPORT>:5000 <imagename>`

Comment: FYI you will need to update chromedriver-binary to match the current stable version of chrome or this will error when you try to run "Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79"

Comment: Yes @LeonKyriacou I agree. Here is how I automated the version matching between google chrome and the chromedriver :

wget -O LATEST_RELEASE http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE && \
latest=$(cat LATEST_RELEASE) && \
sed -i "s/XXXX/$latest/g" requirements.txt && \

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to run it in headless mode

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

this is how I do it in ruby

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
chromeOptions: {args: %w[ no-sandbox headless disable-gpu window-size=1280,1000 ]})

Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, http_client: client, desired_capabilities: capabilities)
```

You can pretty much adapt your code in python

also consider installing some font libriaries that chrome needs to run on headless

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -qq -y install  libxpm4 libxrender1 libgtk2.0-0 libnss3\ 
       libgconf-2-4  libpango1.0-0 libxss1 libxtst6 fonts-liberation\ 
       libappindicator1 xdg-utils

RUN apt-get -y install \
               xvfb gtk2-engines-pixbuf \
               xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base xfonts-scalable \
               imagemagick x11-apps zip
```