# Getting ChromeDriver from Selenium

Tags: python, django, docker, selenium

I'm dockerizing my Python-Selenium application, and have this three lines in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get update -qqy --no-install-recommends &&
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323271/how-to-run-selenium-with-chrome-in-docker), I first launched a standalone chrome browser with this command:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

Added this to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox
    ports:
    - 4444:4444
```

And edited my scrap function to the following:

```
def scrap_function(url):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_prefs = {}
    chrome_options.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
    chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
    driver = webdriver.Remote("http://172.18.0.3:4444/wd/hub", options=chrome_options)
```

I got the remote url from the log, and after these changes running `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`. Seems it is going to the function correctly, but it isn't returning any results nor error messages. Is the webdriver configuration okay? Seems it is going there but the function isn't returning any values.

Comment: You should add Google Chrome driver path.

Comment: check this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323271/how-to-run-selenium-with-chrome-in-docker

Comment: I was following that answer, and edited the code to using a remote. However the function itself isn't returning any results nor errors (only a print statement just before accessing the function). Any ideas? I edited the first post.

Comment: Just use google chrome driver inside container.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit, please?

Comment: Try this tutorial https://alexis-le-baron.com/en/django-selenium-docker/ or https://gist.github.com/matt-bertoncello/a7296c4fc6cdbb8424ffa26b2b9b9257

Comment: I'll check them, thank you.

Comment: What is this `chrome_options = Options()`? What is `Options()`?

Comment: It comes from 'from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options'