Upgrading to selenium/standalone-chrome:127.0 Gives 'DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist' and cannot start chrome
I have the following docker file and everything works fine (I can make calls to websites, etc) with with 126.0 using headless=new . But when I upgrade to 127.0 I get an error (note session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist). Does anyone know a solution or how to diagnose? Error is:
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: '564b16878950', ip: '172.17.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.25.0', revision: '8a8aea2337'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.6.16-linuxkit', java.version: '17.0.11'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Mac..., --disable-extensions, --disable-gpu, --no-sandbox, --incognito, --disable-application-cache, --disable-dev-shm-usage], extensions: []}, pageLoadStrategy: eager}]}]' ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace='org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: '564b16878950', ip: '172.17.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.25.0', revision: '8a8aea2337'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.6.16-linuxkit', java.version: '17.0.11'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Mac..., --disable-extensions, --disable-gpu, --no-sandbox, --incognito, --disable-application-cache, --disable-dev-shm-usage], extensions: []}, pageLoadStrategy: eager}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:61)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:245)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)


I am already using:
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless=new");
        arguments.add("disable-infobars");
        arguments.add("--disable-gpu");
        arguments.add("--no-sandbox");
        arguments.add("--incognito");
        arguments.add("--disable-application-cache");
        arguments.add("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

I am using maven build with the latest version, so I do not think that is the root cause:
<selenium.constructs.version>4.25.0</selenium.constructs.version>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-os</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-session-map-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-session-map-redis</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v127</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v128</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v129</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v85</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-manager</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-http</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-json</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chromium-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.constructs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Dockerfile:
ARG CHROME_VERSION=127.0

# Stage 1: Pre-built Selenium Standalone Chrome image
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:${CHROME_VERSION} as chrome

# See https://hub.docker.com/_/amazoncorretto
# Stage 2: Use Amazon Corretto as the base image, can also do 'FROM amazoncorretto:17' to get latest
FROM amazoncorretto:17.0.11-al2
# Currently using latest corretto; if need to fix a version then do amazoncorretto:17.0.8-al2

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323271/how-to-run-selenium-with-chrome-in-docker
#https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux
# Install necessary dependencies to run chrome in headless mode
RUN yum install -y libX11 libXcomposite libXcursor libXdamage libXext libXi libXtst cups-libs libXScrnSaver libXrandr alsa-lib pango atk at-spi2-atk gtk3 coreutils

# Copy Chrome and ChromeDriver from the first stage
COPY --from=chrome /usr/bin/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
COPY --from=chrome /opt/google/chrome/ /opt/google/chrome/

# Set environment variables for Chrome and ChromeDriver
ENV CHROME_BIN=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_BIN=/usr/bin/chromedriver

# In the original consulting file CHROMEDRIVER_PORT, CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS, and CHROMEDRIVER_URL_BASE are not set
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_PORT 4444
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS "127.0.0.1"
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_URL_BASE ''

# App Setup
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5005

# Copy application JAR into the image
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

# Run application
# Note timeout value should be set to be at least resourceleak.maxLifetimeMs
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Xmx600m", "/app.jar"]

